# Do gyroscopes still work inside event horizon?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, event-horizon, gyroscopes

Imagine a gyroscope falls into the event horizon of a supermassive black hole, what would happen to the gyroscope? will it remains in the same position before it falls into the event horizon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The obvious problem is spaghettification, but for supermassive black holes tidal forces can be small (at the horizon at least). They would deform the gyroscope, causing it to lose energy by dissipation in the material (or just break). A more important effect is that there would also be a tidal torque induced on it, making it precess.

Ken-ichi Sakina showed that [a freely falling gyroscope will orient so its spin axis becomes radial](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00772614), but here the description is entirely in terms of parallel transport of the vector rather than torques. [This is called geodetic precession](https://www.mas.ncl.ac.uk/library/display_pdf.php?id=249#page=10). If the black hole is rotating there will be frame dragging that changes the trajectory (and this depends on the relative angular momentum), but also [Lense-Thirring precession](https://www.mas.ncl.ac.uk/library/display_pdf.php?id=249#page=15) of the gyroscope. [One can make exact analogues of the gravitational case with the electromagnetic case](https://centra.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/%7Ebhw/Costa.pdf). One of the cool effects of this is [a slight deviation from geodesic motion](https://centra.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/%7Ebhw/Costa.pdf#page=36) even for a nonrotating hole if the gyroscope doesn't fall along an entirely radial geodesic.

Comment: Some comments: 1) Lense-Thirring precession is also the result of parallel transport (but know in a background with spin, like Kerr). 2) The slight deviation from geodesic motion due to the angular momentum of the gyroscope (the Mathison-Papapetrou-Dixon force), is (for a sufficiently compact gyroscope) typically smaller than the deviation due to the gyroscope having its own gravitational field (the gravitational self-force).